# The sequence of functions $\frac{x}{1+x^n}$ is not uniformly convergent on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The sequence of functions $\frac{x}{1+x^n}$ is not uniformly convergent on $(0,\infty)$. Is there any subinterval where it is uniformly convergent ?

Comment: see my solution!

Answer (score 1):

What is the limit function? Is it continuous? What do you know about the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions?

Answer (score 1):

Let $g_n(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^n}$. Then $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty} g_n(x)=x$, if $x\in (0,1)$, since $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}x^n=0$ if $x\in (0,1)$, $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}g_n(1)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}g_n(x)=0$, if $x\in (1,+\infty)$, since $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}x^n=+\infty$ if $x\in (1,+\infty)$. Then $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty} g_n(x)=g(x)$, with
$$
g(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
x,& x\in (0,1)\\
\frac{1}{2}, &x=1\\
0, & x>0.
\end{array}\right.
$$
Since $g$ is not continuous, $g_n$ is not uniformly convergent.